# Nuxt3 Plugin Strapi: How to return only one result using FindOne with populate parameter?

Tags: strapi, nuxtjs3

Using Nuxt3 and the Strapi v4 Plugin to create a blog.
Using the `findOne` function to retrieve ONE article.

However using the `populate` parameter to also retrieve relational parameters such as images:

```
findOne<Article>('articles', { populate: "images"}, id)
```

returns a list of ALL articles.
I want only my one article!

How do I get only the result for my given ID including the relations (images) when using the `findOne` function with the `populate` paramter?

---

Docs I consulted:

- Strapi Docs on Parameters: https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/database-apis-reference/rest/populating-fields.html#field-selection
- Strapi Nuxt Docs: https://strapi.nuxtjs.org/usage
- 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query syntax is wrong. `findOne` takes `id` as the second parameter and `options` as the third parameter as below:

###### Syntax:

```js
findOne(uid: string, id: ID, parameters: Params) ⇒ Entry
```

###### Solution in Strapi:

```js
const entry = await strapi.entityService.findOne('api::article.article', 1, {
  fields: ['title', 'description'],
  populate: { category: true },
});
```

###### Solution in Nuxt Strapi:

```js
const entry = await findOne<Article>('articles', 1, {
  fields: ['title', 'description'],
  populate: { images: true },
});
```

###### Reference:

- [Entity Service Api](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/database-apis-reference/entity-service-api.html)
- [findOne - Nuxt Strapi](https://strapi.nuxtjs.org/usage/#findone)

Comment: Guess I missed that. thanks for providing the links and both code examples!